# Emulate vim modeline in evil mode

Tags: evil

As a background, vim modelines is a magic comment in the text file that sets some of the vim options. It is similar to emacs' file variables.

A modeline like `;; vim: set expandtab :` in a lisp file enables the option `expandtab` which convert tab character to spaces.

Is there a package that does emulation of vim modelines for emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly enough, there is such a thing: https://github.com/cinsk/emacs-vim-modeline

I'd recommend to add file-local or directory-local variables to the affected files though. Alternatively, using https://editorconfig.org/ for an editor-agnostic way to specify configuration.